# $(AB:A) = B$ for every finitely generated $B$ does not imply that $A$ is a cancellation ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I am stuck at the following exercise:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring  and let $A$ and $B$ be ideals in $R$ with $(AB:A) = B$ for every finitely generated $B$. Show that this does not imply that $A$ is a cancellation ideal, i.e. $(AB:A) = B$ for every $B$.

Related to this topic I already know that $(R:B) = B$ and $(B:R) = R$ and I also know that in  $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ holds $$(2,1+\sqrt{-3})(2,1+\sqrt{-3}) = (2)(2,1+\sqrt{-3}),$$ but obviously $(2,1+\sqrt{-3}) \ne 2$.

However, I just can not find an ideal such that $(AB:A) = B$ for ***every*** finitely generated  $B$ that is not a cancellation ideal. Could you please give me a hint?

To be clear: It is perfectly fine if $R$ is an integral domain or something, it just has to be commutative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the ring $R:=\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\cdots$. Clearly $R$ is a Von Neumann regular ring and so each its finitely generated ideal is principal. Now set $A:=\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\cdots$. Then $A$ is a proper ideal of $R$ such that $AA=A$ and so $A$ is not a cancelation ideal. But if $B$ is a finitely generated of $R$, then there exists $r\in R$ such that $B=\langle r\rangle $ and clearly we have $(Ar:A)=\langle r\rangle$, that is, $(AB:A)=B$.